# How to get customer custom attribute value in observer in magento 2.2.X?

Tags: magento2.2, event-observer

I have created a customer custom attribute like(gst_no).
In my Observer where I get my customer data I want to get the value of this attribute too.

```
 $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
 $order_id = $order->getIncrementId();
 $shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress(); // shipping address
 $email = $shippingAddress->getEmail();
 $customer = $order->getCustomer();
 $customer_id = $order->getCustomerId();
 $gstno = $customer->getResource()->getAttribute('gst_no')->getFrontend()->getValue($customer);
 $order->setGstNo($customer_id);
 $order->save();
```

But I am not getting attribute value.,can anyone help?

Comment: If you are not getting the value then load the customer and then try to get custom values.

Comment: please check my answer and accept if it's helpful for you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use this below code :

```
/**
 *  @var \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface
 *  @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order
*/
protected $_customerRepositoryInterface;
protected $_order;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order,
)
{
    $this->_customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
    $this->_order = $order;
}
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{ 
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $orderdetails = $this->_order->load( $order->getId());
    $customerId = $orderdetails ->getCustomerId();
    $customeratt = $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->getById($customerId);
    $cattrValue = $customeratt->getCustomAttribute('gst_no');
}
```

Comment: this is not worked for me rohan

Comment: what report or error generate? can you please tell me?

Comment: i think after place order not get customer data in observer

Comment: $this->logger->info("gstno==>".$cattrValue."<");
i have debug data but not getting value in $cattrvalue variable

Comment: see my updated answer. remove generated folder and cache clean.

Comment: its ok rohan issue was resolved

Comment: Happy coding !! Happy to help :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the below code -

```
$gstNoAttribute = $customer->getCustomAttribute('gst_no');
if(isset($gstNoAttribute)) {
    $gstno = $gstNoAttribute->getValue();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use customer repository.

The repo injection will give you the customer custom attributes.

Comment: Hey it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

This is correct answer which worked for me.

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
//$customer = $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->getById($order->getCustomerId());
$customer = $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->get($order->getCustomerEmail());
$gstno = $customer->getCustomAttribute('gst_no')->getValue();
$this->logger->info("gstno==>".$gstno."<");
$order->setGstNo($gstno);
$order->save();
```

Comment: this only works when you have the flat tables created for your customer entity and your custom attribute is already been added into the columns of those flat tables data. normally flat tables for eav attributes are created through indexer.

Answer (score 1):

Custom attributes does not added into the select list with the customer data retrieved from `Order` object. You can only use this `$customer->getResource()->getAttribute('gst_no')->getFrontend()->getValue($customer);` when you load the customer object through repository.

For your situation, from the `order` object,  get the `customer data` and from that, get `customer Id` and then use the customerrepostory to get full information (including the custom attributes) and then use `$customer->getData('gst_no')` to get the details of custom attribute.

Answer (score 0):

**Try below code**

```
    namespace Vendor\Modelename\Observer;
    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
    use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;

 
class Dropshipprice implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $customerSession;
    protected $customerRepositoryInterface;
    protected $productFactory;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory $customerSession, \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface, ProductFactory $productFactory)
    {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $customer = $this->customerSession->create();
        if ($customer->isLoggedIn() && $customer->getCustomerGroupId() == 4) {
            $id = $customer->getCustomerId();
            $customerData = $this->customerRepositoryInterface->getById($id);
            $dropshitDiscount = $customerData->getCustomAttribute('dropshit_discount')->getValue();

            $item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');
            $productId = $item->getProduct()->getId();
            $_product = $this->productFactory->create()->load($productId);
            $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );
            $finalprice = $_product->getFinalPrice();

            if (!empty($_product->getPriceDropship()) && $_product->getPriceDropship() != '0') {
                $dropshipfinalprice = $_product->getPriceDropship();
            } else {
                $dropshitDiscount = $dropshitDiscount;
                $dropshipfinalprice = $finalprice * (1 - ($dropshitDiscount / 100));
            }

            $price = $dropshipfinalprice;
            $item->setCustomPrice($price);
            $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
            $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
        }
    }
}
```